# EOFError whilst pickling in Python

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

Here's the problem - I'm trying to pickle, and then unpickle hiscores. When I use pickle.load, Python seems to think that I'm trying to load a file called 'Pickle' that I have. Here's the code:

```
def recieve_hiscores():
    hiscores_file = open("hiscores_file.dat", "rb")
    for i in hiscores_file:
        hiscores = pickle.load(hiscores_file)
        hiscores = str(hiscores)
        print(hiscores)
```

Here's the pickling code:

```
def send_hiscores(score):
    hiscores_file = open("hiscores_file.dat", "ab")
    pickle.dump(score, hiscores_file)
    hiscores_file.close()
```

And here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python31\My Updated Trivia Challenge.py", line 106, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python31\My Updated Trivia Challenge.py", line 104, in main
recieve_hiscores()
File "C:\Python31\My Updated Trivia Challenge.py", line 56, in recieve_hiscores
hiscores = pickle.load(hiscores_file)
File "C:\Python31\lib\pickle.py", line 1365, in load
encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
EOFError
```

Don't worry if there's any other mistakes, I'm still learning, but I can't work this out.

Comment: Your `hiscores_file.dat` doesn't contain a complete Python object. Show us your pickling code and what you're pickling and maybe we can see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you iterate over the file, you get newline separated lines. This is NOT how you get a series of pickles. The end of file error is raised because the first line has a partial pickle.

Try this:

```
def recieve_hiscores():
    highscores = []
    with open("hiscores_file.dat", "rb") as hiscores_file:
        try:
            while True:
                hiscore = pickle.load(hiscores_file)
                hiscore = str(hiscore)
                print(hiscore)
                highscores.append(hiscore)
        except EOFError:
            pass
    return highscores
```